# .NET Standard 2.0 logging NLOG gives System.TypeInitializationException

Tags: nlog, .net-standard-2.0, typeinitializeexception

I did 2 projects to test out NLog on a .NET Framework 4.6.1 standard console app and on .NET Standard 2.0 Library. My intention is to port as much code as I can to .NET Standard 2.0 for future multiplatform compatibility.

Both share the same code but the .NET Standard version produces an exception.

Here's the code

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Writing log");
Logger _errorLog = LogManager.GetLogger("ErrorsLogger");
Logger _tradesLog = LogManager.GetLogger("TradesLogger");
_errorLog.Error("This is the log message!!!");
Console.WriteLine("End log");
Console.Read();
```

Here's the App.Config

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog"/>
  </configSections>
  <nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <targets>
      <target name="ErrorsLogger" xsi:type="File" fileName="ErrorsLog.txt" />
      <target name="TradesLogger" xsi:type="File" fileName="TradesLog.txt" />
    </targets>

    <rules>
      <logger name="ErrorsLogger" minlevel="Info" writeTo="ErrorsLogger" />
      <logger name="TradesLogger" minlevel="Info" writeTo="TradesLogger" />
    </rules>
  </nlog>
</configuration>
```

I get the log fine in the .NET 4.6.1 Console app and produces the expected log file with the log message in it.

If I run the .NET Standard 2.0 library through some Microsoft Unit Test project I get this exception when it tries to call _errorLog.GetLogger

> UnitTestProject.UnitTest1.TestMethod1 threw exception: 
>   System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'NLog.LogManager' threw an exception. --->
>   System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'NLog.LogFactory' threw an exception. --->
>   System.MissingMethodException: Method not found:
>   'System.AppDomainSetup System.AppDomain.get_SetupInformation()'.

EDIT:
[Nuget NLOG Version: 4.4.12](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog/4.4.12)

Exception thrown in a non static method:

About the non static method to get a better exception:

The exception is thrown at the GetLogger("X") level, which is a non static constructor. The initialization routine crashes even before trying to log something.

In addition, I get a WARNING (yellow exclamation mark) in the error list saying:

> Warning       The 'configuration' element is not declared.

Adding internal logging doesn't produce any output. This is the configuration i have used, starting from their [Internal logging guide](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging):

```
        InternalLogger.LogLevel = LogLevel.Trace;
        InternalLogger.LogFile = @"C:\temp\int.txt";
        InternalLogger.LogToConsole = true;
        InternalLogger.LogToConsoleError = true;
        InternalLogger.LogWriter = new StringWriter(new StringBuilder());
        InternalLogger.LogToTrace = true;
        LogManager.ThrowConfigExceptions = true;
        LogManager.ThrowExceptions = true;
        Logger logger = LogManager.GetLogger("foo");
```

I'm administrator and Visual Studio 2017 is started as administrator and I have permission to write in C:\temp ad .NET 4.6.1 console application is able to write in that folder and it's in the same project.

The internal log file is empty and the Unit test project runs the test successfully.

I have no clue of what is happening. No error is thrown now.

Any suggestion to debug the issue is welcome.

An [ISSUE](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/2522) on GitHub is already opened.

[HERE](https://files.fm/u/b54cp6ck) is a test solution that I made to show you (PASSWORD: logging123). Now that I've updated to Nlog 4.5 you will see that the .NET framework solution throws an error trying to get an old version of Nlog (that I've never referenced) and that .NET Core unit test solution works but doesn't produce any file.

Comment: Seems trouble with decency troubles. Please list all the nlog (nuget) versions

Comment: If you encapsulate the call to the logmanager is a non static method, you will get probably a better inner exception

Comment: @Julian added. About the non static, read the further details

Comment: Support for .netstandard 1.5 and 2.0 was added in version 4.5, currently in beta.

Comment: @HansPassant I like how you are pointing me to the right direction and the actual mantainer of the package which is Julian didn't even gave me hint about this.

Stupid me for not being able to find that info alone though.

Comment: @HansPassant now with the 4.5 it doesn't fires exceptions but doesn't produce a log file either. It just fails silently

Comment: There is not much point in telling me about it, [tell the guys that work on it](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues).  Click the New Issue button.  Pretty important to say more than "it just fails silently".

Comment: @HansPassant [Already did](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/2522). They suggest to go here first. Funny.

**Pretty important to say more than "it just fails silently"**
Well, if only their internal logger worked :)

Comment: Can you look at the inner exception property of the thrown exception?  That might tell you something more, like the NLog.Config file is not found or something.  Might have to add a DeployItem Attribute to the test class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your zipped solution is password protected, so now it is just me guessing, but it looks like you are using app.config to hold nlog.config.

Pretty sure app.config are not being used by NetCoreApps. Try to put your Nlog-config in a separate file called `nlog.config` and make sure it is `Copy Always` (In Visual Studio File Properties).

Comment: As I've said, very stupid by me, password added. Password is logging123

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same issue though I was running .NET 4.7. I updated my NLog package from 4.4.12 to [4.5.0-rc04](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog/4.5.0-rc04) and it worked. Knowing its pre-release you may want to be cautions about putting it on live environment though.

Comment: So you gotta take it from the website? It's not available on NuGet

Comment: No. Follow the link. It'll take you to NuGet website and to the particular package itself. From there you can copy the instructions for Package Manager.

Comment: Now it doesn't throw exceptions, but it doesn't write any file. I Followed the troubleshooting at https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting to no avail.

Damn.... :(